# How Can I Use a Regular Expression to Test for a Specific Decimal?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a field where the user needs to input the width of their window. It needs to be between 16.75 and 48 and only in .25 increments (so it has to end in .00, .25, .50, .75). I have tried the following to test my regular expressions on the number 31.25 but the all return false. I've trolled the internet but can't find much help for a regex novice like me. Can someone please help me with the regex for this?

Here is the field:

```
<input type="text" id="windowWidth" onchange="basePrice()">
```

Here is the JS:

```
function basePrice()
{
    var windowWidth = document.getElementById("windowWidth").value;
    var windowHeight = document.getElementById("windowHeight").value;

    if (windowWidth != "" && windowWidth > 16.75 && windowWidth < 48)
    {
         alert(/^\d{2}\.[00]$/.test(windowWidth));
         alert(/^\d{2}\.[25]$/.test(windowWidth));
         alert(/^\d{2}\.[50]$/.test(windowWidth));
         alert(/^\d{2}\.[75]$/.test(windowWidth));
    }
    else
    {
         alert("error");
         exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI, practically everything you need to know about regular expressions can be found at www.regular-expressions.info

Comment: No, I guess that's the part I missed. Thanks for your condescending remark without a useful solution.

Comment: @kaitlynjanine Just for learning purposes, make sure you have a look at other answers that doesn't involve regular expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably combine them to test if they fell within your range and then used the following regex :

```
/^\d{2}\.(00|25|50|75)$/
```

Comment: Oops! I'll need to fix that.

Comment: I was hoping this would work since it's shorter, but it always returns false. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I have the need for a similar RegEx, I made a slight adjustment so the user doesn't have to type in the meaningless trailing zeros: `/^\d{2}\.(0|00|25|5|50|75)$/`

Answer (score 3):

Remove `[` and `]`, that is used for character class in regex:

```
alert(/^\d{2}\.(?:00|25|50|75)$/.test(windowWidth));
```

For ex: `[00]` means match literal 0 or 0

OR `[25]` means match 2 or 5

Comment: Thanks for that info. I'll have to remember that next time. You're awesome!

Answer (score 2):

You do not need a regular expression for this. You can simply use math expressions.

```
var n = 35.23;

n >= 16.75 && n <= 48 && !(n % .25); //false

n = 35.25;

n >= 16.75 && n <= 48 && !(n % .25); //true
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a non-regex way of doing it, which is possibly more efficient and less messy:

```
var has25decimal = (windowWidth * 100) % 25 == 0
```

The `%` (modulo) gives you the remainder after the number has been divided by 25. When that is 0 the number can be divided by 25.

Comment: It took quite a while before I get notified of your answer. I had finish to write mine when I got notified so I decided to post it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use html 5 input attributes, then you could try this (without regular expressions):

```
<input type="number" id="windowWidth" onchange="basePrice()" min="16.75" max="48" step="0.25">
```

This would enforce the minimum and maximum and change by 0.25 when clicking the up or down arrows.

Comment: +1 Pretty neat, I did not know this. HTML5 still haven't reached my work place... hehe ;)